# How can I work with dates with years smaller than 1 or bigger than 9999 in python?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

I am making a Python script that converts real-life dates into dates for a fantasy world.

However, I cannot represent years smaller than 1 or bigger than 9999 using the `datetime` module, and they may occasionally appear. Is there any way to represent these dates in Python?

I tried using the `datetime` module but it doesn't support years smaller than 1 or bigger than 9999.

Comment: If you are using non-standard dates then you need to define your own data type.

Comment: They are legitimate real-life dates, just that they have a very strange range. For example, this day is year 4062 when converted to fake date.

Comment: You might find [BC dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15857797/4996248) interesting. Some of the answers mention astronomy as a use-case for a more expansive approach to dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your case might be an unique case as it is not the common objective for most people using `datetime` module. You might have to do this manually, my suggestion is as follow:

1. Define the rule of transformation/conversion from real-life date into fake date (between 1 - 9999)
2. Write an algorithm to perform the transformation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have a transformation/conversion rule for real-life date to fake date that works for output years between 1 - 9999, that's not what I'm asking for.